# How can I find sibling in Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Following code is simplified html code.

```
 <html>
  ...
  <div class="info">
   <span class="time">2017.01.16</span>
  </div>
  <div class="related_group">
   <ul class="related_list">
    <li>
     <p class="info">
      <span class="time">2016.12.28</span>
     </p>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
   <span class="time">2017.01.26</span>
  </div>
  <div class="related_group">
   <ul class="related_list">
    <li>
     <p class="info">
      <span class="time">2017.01.30</span>
     </p>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  ...
 </html>
```

This pattern repeated many time and I want to get data like 
**2017.01.16** and **2017.01.26**

So I was use Beautiful Soup in python.

```
for item in soup.find_all("span", {"class" : "time"}):
    source=source+str(item.find_all(text=True))
```

This code find date data but it find also useless data 
**2016.12.28** and **2017.01.30**

For more precised result, I tried with **find_next_siblings**

```
for item in soup.find_next_siblings("span", {"class" : "time"}):
    source=source+str(item.find_next_siblings())
```

You may know, it doesn't work.
Of course I searched reference and read it.
I can't understand enough because lack of English..
If you don't mind, could you help me with code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html=""" <html>

  <div class="info">
   <span class="time">2017.01.16</span>
  </div>

  <div class="related_group">
   <ul class="related_list">
    <li>
     <p class="info">
      <span class="time">2016.12.28</span>
     </p>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="info">
   <span class="time">2017.01.26</span>
  </div>

  <div class="related_group">
   <ul class="related_list">
    <li>
     <p class="info>
      <span class="time">2017.01.30</span>
     </p>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

 </html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
s = soup.find_all('div', class_=['info', 'related_group'])
s = iter(s)

for a in s:
    print a.text.strip(), '---', next(s).text.strip()
```

Output:

```
2017.01.16 --- 2016.12.28
2017.01.26 --- 2017.01.30
```

Comment: I thank you your help. Although your code wasn't match perfectly, I appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

```
soup.find_all('div', class_='info')
```

out:

```
[<div class="info">
 <span class="time">2017.01.16</span>
 </div>, <div class="info">
 <span class="time">2017.01.26</span>
 </div>]
```

The tag you want is under `div` tag.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Your code wasn't I intended but you replied me.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
times = []
items = soup.find_all('div', {"class" : "info"})
for item in items:
    tmp = item.select(".time")
    t = tmp[0].text
    times.append(t)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I fixed my code and it works!Also your comment make me improve my code more effective.